# Cannot call value of non-function type 'Object?'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

I know this question was asked before a few times but I don't get it.
Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Fetch colors
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Color")

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "number", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    do {
        let colors = try managedObjectContext!.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Color]

        for var i in 0...4 {
            let saveColorBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: i * 70 , y: Int(self.view.frame.maxY - 120), width: 50, height: 50))
            saveColorBtn.tag = i

            if let savedColor = colors.first(where: {$0.number == i}) {
                saveColorBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(savedColor.r), green: CGFloat(savedColor.g), blue: CGFloat(savedColor.b), alpha: CGFloat(savedColor.a))
            } else {
                saveColorBtn.backgroundColor = .lightGray
            }

            self.view.addSubview(saveColorBtn)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError
    {
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

When I search for $0.number == 0 it works fine but when I search for $0.number == i I get the error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'Color?'"

"colors" is an array with objects of type "color"

Comment: Works fine for me when I'm testing, but I've had to construct my own `Color' type (assuming that `number` property is of type `Int`). Could you supply a [minimal, **complete**, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us? We can't help you spot the error if you hide relevant context for us (also likely that you might spot the error yourself when you construct a complete example).

Comment: I put in the whole code. I fetch the saved colors from the core data and add 5 buttons of which each has the saved color or a gray color as background color.

Comment: I still can't verify this example (and it's no longer minimal). You still haven't showed us the definition of the `Color` type. If you construct a **minimal** and **complete** example yourself (rather than directly looking at your actual implemention), it is usually quite possible that you will solve the problem yourself. Please read the page I linked to in my previous comments: following its guidelines and advices will raise the possibility that someone can help you out with your questions.

Comment: Ok thanks I will take a look

Comment: Good luck! (My guess is that the _type_ of the `number` property of type `Color` is a good place to start: seing that you may compare it to an integer literal (`0`) but not to an integer (`i`)).

Comment: Oh man, that's it. Sometimes it's so easy that you can't see the solution. Thanks a lot.